# How to format date and time values for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, date, time, format

Can't believe I have to ask this here. Even googling didn't help.

I want to do this:

```
insert into atable (adatefield,atimefield,adatetimefield) values (A,B,C);
```

- adatefield is defined as DATE
- atimefield is defined as TIME
- adatetimefield is defined as DATETIME

What do I put for A, B and C?

It's nice that it's free but the documentation for SQLite is awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A date, time and datetime field will actually all store datetime, it just depends on what you insert into it, and they will all work with date strings.

You can

```
insert into atable values("2010-11-16","14:12:22","2010-11-16 14:12:22");
```

or you can actually just insert "2010-11-16 14:12:22" into all the fields and then select them back with:

```
select date(adatefield), time(atimefield), datetime(adatetimefield) from atable;
```

If however you want to make sure that the fields only contain exactly a date,time or datetime and you're inserting from variables, then you can

```
insert into atable values(date(thedate),time(thedate),datetime(thedate));
```

Sqlites typelessness makes some things really easy, but can confuse or complicate some other things.