# How to use SQLite decimal precision notation

Tags: sqlite

[Again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193241/how-to-format-date-and-time-values-for-sqlite) I find myself frustrated by the awful SQLite documentation.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html gives an example of defining a decimal field as `decimal(10,5)` but it doesn't explain what 10 is and what 5 is.

I am sure that 10 is the total number of digits stored, but I don't know what 5 means. Is it the number of digits **before** the decimal place or **after** the decimal place?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> [decimal is one of several] common datatype names from more traditional SQL implementations are
>   converted into [SQLite] affinities

(An affinity is about as close to the idea of a data type that SQLite has. Read http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for more about this.)

By this logic, it seems safe to use the documentation from MySQL to explain the SQLite decimal precision notation.

According to http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value
>   with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the
>   salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99.

So `decimal(10,5)` indicates that the field should be used to store a value up to ten digits in length, with up to five digits before the decimal point and up to five digits after the decimal point.

Of course, any value entered will be stored, even if it doesn't keep to these rules, which means that the field definition is basically documentation.

Comment: Cool... this is the first time I've seen that the best answer actually came from the person who asked the question. Thanks for clarifying in a simple way.

Comment: Update: As of version 3.37.0 (2021-11-27), SQLite provides STRICT tables that do rigid type enforcement, for developers who prefer that kind of thing. 
However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.

Answer (score 43):

That page says:

> In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.

Which means that the declared data type has no effect on the values that can be stored in the column.

The example explains that a `DECIMAL(10, 5)` column has a numeric affinity, i.e., values stored in that column are preferred to be numbers:

```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable(X DECIMAL(10, 5));
> INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1), ('2'), (1.23456789), ('hello'), (x'42');
> SELECT X, typeof(X) FROM MyTable;
1           integer
2           integer
1.23456789  real
hello       text
B           blob
```

Otherwise, the type is ignored; you could use just as well use `DECIMAL(-123, 999999)`, or `FLUFFY BUNNIES`.

Comment: So are you saying that decimal(1,1) is the same as decimal(99,53) ?

Comment: In other words, that it doesn't matter how a field is defined, the whole value will always be stored unchanged?

Comment: Yes (except for changes due to affinity, like the string `'2'` in the example).

Comment: Ok so now I understand that the decimal definition is basically suggestive documentation. Please can you tell me how to write it properly? E.g. my original question

Comment: Sorry; your original question is about DECIMAL, and I answered what it does in SQLite (nothing). I suspect your *actual* problem is [something different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but you never mentioned what that problem is. Please [create a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and say what exactly you want the database to do with the value in the field. (Do you want a minimum or a maximum number of digits? Before or after the decimal point? And what should happen with out-of-range values?)