# Ruby on Rails Precision and Scale not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, precision

I am following the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and appear to have an issue with either the understanding of what scale is supposed to do or my code is incorrect. I have the precision set to 8 and the scale set 2 for the price field. I would expect this to mean that when I add a product in the form that it would only show 2 digits past the decimal point regardless of what number I enter. For example entering the price as 45.12345 would show up as 45.12 after product creation but I'm seeing the whole exactly as I entered it.

Here is schema.rb:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141109160004) do

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "descritpion"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: What database are you using. The default sqlite3?

Comment: Yes sqlite3, I would have thought the book would have mentioned this limitation as it recommends you use that database.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the default SQLite3 database, you should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757722/how-to-use-sqlite-decimal-precision-notation) about decimals in SQLite. Essentially SQLite (as its name implies) does not have all the features of other SQL databases. It ignores both precision and scale attributes, and will just store the number as a `real`.

The most relevant part from that other answer:

> So decimal(10,5) indicates that the field should be used to store a
>   value up to ten digits in length, with up to five digits before the
>   decimal point and up to five digits after the decimal point.
>
> Of course, any value entered will be stored, even if it doesn't keep
>   to these rules, which means that the field definition is basically
>   documentation.