# sqlite type-name with two optional signed numbers, what does it mean?

Tags: sqlite

I guess this is a very naive question but could not goolge it.

I see in various pages on sqlite site that mention a type-name can have up to 2 signed numbers

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html
https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

In the later there is an example DECIMAL(10,5)

What this mean? I suppose it is a kind of magnitude/precision, what would 2 numbers mean for both integer and text?

Thanx in advance.
Phi

Comment: It is given as an example of the things that will map to `NUMERIC`, SQLite does not in any way care about those two numbers. These two numbers mean something for *other* database engines, usually total digit precision and fractional digit precision, but SQLite simply uses `NUMERIC`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use SQLite decimal precision notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757722/how-to-use-sqlite-decimal-precision-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Please Look at this question for more clarification.
[How to use SQLite decimal precision notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757722/how-to-use-sqlite-decimal-precision-notation)

It says, the declared data type has no effect on the values that can be stored in the column.

DECIMAL(10, 5) column has a numeric affinity so It stores Text '2' as integer 2.

Comment: Thank you all, well I didn't spotted the ocurence withthe exact same example  DECIMAL(10,5), sorry about that. Ok nice I will ignore them :)