# How to limit numeric column type to certain symbols before and after decimal separator in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, limit

I want to limit numeric column type to 10 symbols before decimal separator and 4 symbols after decimal separator. I executed the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE scustdisc ADD COLUMN spec_price numeric(10,4)
```

The command executed without errors but when I try to insert value in spec_price 10.123456 I am able to do it. It should give error and the value not to be inserted. Am I wrong in my alter command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SQLite decimal precision notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757722/how-to-use-sqlite-decimal-precision-notation)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a dynamic type system and the column types have a limited impact, but can be virtually any name. They are resolved to one of TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL or BLOB.

- numeric(0,0) - numeric(99999999,99999999)  and more resolve to NUMERIC.

As such 10,4 4,10 etc means nothing and makes no difference to SQLite.

With one exception bar constraints a column may hold any type of value. The column type only comes into play in determining the way the data is stored.

A must read is [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

You may also find [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

You may be able to resolve this by using a CHECK constraint [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) or by using a `TRIGGER` or multiple `TRIGGER`s.

You could format the number(s) appropriately when they are displayed.

You could utilise the `round(x,y)` function [Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round)