# Problem where I have to cast columns in order to correctly use them in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Does anyone know what might cause me to have to cast columns in order to correctly use functions on them? I think the problem originates with how I insert data in python, but it's confusing to me because I've now had the problem with two columns in the same set of data.

For reference my DB Schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
    `file_path` TEXT,
    `mtime` INTEGER,
    `file_text` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`file_path`)
);
```

I would like to be able to search a column named `file_text` using LIKE, but it only works if I cast it as TEXT and then use LIKE.

This works:

```
SELECT file_path, file_text FROM files WHERE CAST(file_text AS TEXT) LIKE '%how%'
```

Gives 103 rows.

This does NOT work:

```
SELECT file_path, file_text FROM files WHERE file_text LIKE '%how%'
```

Gives 0 rows.

If I input data manually through SQLite Browser LIKE works correctly with the `file_text` column, but otherwise doesn't.

Initially file_text was a BLOB type (which was what I changed to text, and also deleted and reloaded data into the DB file), which was the first thing I changed when it did not work.

Previously I had this problem with the mtime column, and checking whether or not one file had a lower or higher mtime. I fixed this by doing:

`UPDATE temp SET mtime = CAST(mtime AS INTEGER)`

After loading all the data in, but I don't think this is something I should need to do either, and might just be covering up an unintended problem.

I load rows with:

```
def insert_file(file_tuple, conn):
    """ 
    Inserts a given tuple containing a file's path, mtime, and its text into a given SQLite3 connection into the files table.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file_tuple : tuple
        The first index should be the file's path, the second should be the
        file's mtime, and the third should be the text in the file.
    conn : sqlite3.connect object
        A connection to the database.
    """
    conn.execute("""INSERT INTO files VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", file_tuple)
```

**TL;DR:  I need to CAST columns in order for SQLite to recognize them as their correct datatype, when I really shouldn't. Any thoughts on why this might be the case are appreciated.**

EDIT:  Reproducible code

```
import sqlite3
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (file_path TEXT, mtime
             INTEGER)""")

for i in range(round(random.random() * 100)):
    conn.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)""", ("TEST", random.random(),))

conn.commit()

for i in conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM test"""):
    print(i)

for i in conn.execute("""SELECT file_path, CAST(mtime AS INTEGER) FROM
                      test"""):
    print(i)
```

Data is supposed to be saved as an integer (and floored/rounded), but when I open it up in SQLite Browser it comes up as what I input. Even when printing it directly from the SQLite connection, it comes up as a non whole number.

Notice that the second for loop prints out 0, as it is flooring the number.

EDIT 3:  I'll keep this up, but the answer is effectively that SQLite does not constrain what you put into a column. I think you can do so with CHECK in some way, but apparently it depends on your version of SQLite. At any rate my problem is effectively solved by just casting all the data in the column as TEXT after it's completely done. It's not how I would have liked to solve the problem, but it works and the only other solution is to probably typecast every input to that column (in Python) as a string with str().

Thanks to anyone who helped.

Comment: If the column really be defined as text, then the cast should not be necessary.  Can you provide a reproducible example of this problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. Answer has been edited with the reproducible code on the INTEGER column.

Comment: You are asking two different questions. For top first part, please post data of  *files* table so we can reproduce. Also, post the code of how you ran queries. Did you call them from Python? For bottom second part, read [@CL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758375/1422451) where data types in SQLite associates with value itself not defined type just as long as it aligns to affinity (i.e., numeric).

Comment: I bet you're still storing blobs in that column. What does `select typeof(file_text) from files` give you?

Comment: You should carefully read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html to get an idea of some of sqlite's peculiarities, btw.

Comment: Also, since you mention you converted those blob columns to text, post the `.schema files` in SQLite CLI.

Comment: Okay there's been like 5 revisions of this comment because I have to keep editing it. So here goes:

I didn't realize loose/whatever typing SQLite uses was a thing. I don't even know why it tells you to input the type of data a column in supposed to be without actually enforcing it.

After rounding mtime before inputting it into the DB it now gives type Integer 100% of the time without cast.

I didn't convert the blob columns to text, I literally remade the DB with the column type changed to TEXT instead of blob.

I'll experiment with how to tell SQL it's text.

Comment: Your integer/floating point example sounds like it's working correctly. If the floating point number you're inserting can't be losslessly converted to an integer, it's stored as a real number.

Comment: I was given incorrect info previously where it was stated that SQL would floor the numbers if I set the column to INTEGER. At any rate the problem is fixed if I make sure numbers are rounded and CAST the file_text column to TEXT when I'm done. If someone wants to take credit for it by making an answer they can feel free, and I'll check them off. It's not really what I wanted, but apparently even using CHECK doesn't actually throw an error in the version of SQLite that I'm in.